# Конструкторы и ключевое слово this (пример)

Tags: java, конструктор, this

```
public class Employee {
    private static int id;
    private int employeeId;
    private String name;
    private String position;
    private int salary;
    private String department;

    public Employee(){
        this("A", "B", 1);
        System.out.println("Empty constructor called");
    }

    public Employee(String name, String position, int salary){
        this(name, position, salary, "IT");
        System.out.println("Constructor with 3 params called");
    }

    private Employee(String name, String position, int salary, String department){
        employeeId = id++;
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.department = department;
        System.out.println("Constructor with 4 params called");
    }

    public int getEmployeeId(){
        return employeeId;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();

    }
}
```

Не понимаю почему так странно выводится информация в консоль:

```
Constructor with 4 params called
Constructor with 3 params called
Empty constructor called
```

Comment: Если ответ помог вам или решил вашу проблему, то примите его, нажав галочку и стрелку вверх рядом с ответом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласен с VBugaenko и позволю себе немного более подробно объяснить (для уточнения).
Первым делом вызывается конструктор без параметров:

```
public Employee()
```

в нем 2 строчки кода:

```
this("A", "B", 1);
```

означает вызов второго конструктора с тремя параметрами, а:

```
System.out.println("Empty constructor called");
```

вывод на консоль текста "Empty constructor called". Так вот в данном месте этот текст **не выводится сразу**, а сначала вызывается конструктор с тремя параметрами - он же раньше был, в первой строчке конструктора. Далее все аналогично: в конструкторе с тремя параметрами сначала вызывается конструктор с четырьмя параметрами:

```
this(name, position, salary, "IT");
```

и следующий вывод на консоль "Constructor with 3 params called" также **сразу не выводится**, пока не вызовится конструктор с четырьмя параметрами. Этот вызванный конструктор (тот, что с четырьмя))) уже не вызывает еще один конструктор, а занимается присвоением значений переменным:

```
employeeId = id++;
    this.name = name;
    this.position = position;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.department = department;
```

и затем выводит на консоль "Constructor with 4 params called". А уже после этого в обратном порядке отрабатываются вывод на консоль "Constructor with 3 params called", и уже в последнюю очередь вывод на консоль из самого первого конструктора без параметров: "Empty constructor called".

Небольшое уточнение - если представленный код будет в одном файле, то он не скомпилируется, т.к. оба класса Test и Employee объявлены как public, а это не разрешено.

Answer (score 1):

Все отработано верно:
был создан объект класса

```
new Employee()
```

и отработал конструктор без параметров (о чем и было сообщение в консоль "Empty constructor called"), в нем был вызван конструктор с 3мя параметрами

```
this("A", "B", 1)
```

и он тоже отлично отработал (соответствующее сообщение в консоль тоже выведено), ну и наконец был вызван конструктор с 4мя параметрами

```
this(name, position, salary, "IT");
```